# Mail Header Hostname/Computer name if behind VPN

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vpn, smtp, headers

When sending mail with a native mail client like Outlook, my hostname is part of the mail header (Received from).
I would like to know if this hostname is also shown if I am connected to a VPN or if the VPN machine's hostname will be shown in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Received:` header shows the sender in three ways:

1. the HELO or EHLO hostname that the sending host *itself* provided;
2. the IP address that the receiving host saw;
3. the "reverse DNS" hostname of the IP address that the receiving host saw.

For example:

```
Received: from BLIZZARD (192-88-99-1.static.example.com [192.88.99.1]) ...
               ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^
                  #1                   #3                    #2
```

Using a VPN will change the IP address seen by the server (and accordingly the rDNS hostname), but it **will not** change the HELO hostname that Outlook reports.

Additionally, if your client generates its own Message-Id, using a VPN will *probably not* change the '@domain' part that the mail app provides. (It depends on whether the mail app uses the hostname, or the DNS "search suffix", or both, or neither.)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the very detailed explanation, I haven't been able to find that information in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for all your sharing.